# communicate programically Dash coin core wallet

Tags: daemon, installation

I have installed dash coin wallet in my amazon server by using instruction from the below url

https://planetcrypton.com/install-dash-daemon

I want to communicate coin wallet via php programme. i just tried the below plugin to connect to the coin wallet from my server. But i coudnt connect to the coin wallet and it says "Empty reply from server0". i added the cofiguration details in the dash.conf file.

i give corresponding values in below configuration set up

```
rpcuser=<some_reallY_long_really_random_username>
rpcpassword=<some_really_long_really_random_password>
alertnotify=echo %s | mail -s "DASH Alert" <your@email-address.com>
server=1
daemon=1
addnode=23.23.186.131
listen=1
logtimestamps=1
maxconnections=256
masternode=0
masternodeaddr=<ip.add.re.ss>:9999
externalip=<ip.add.re.ss>
```

I only set the master node settings in my server because i dont want to connect the master node from the local system.I need to connect the wallet via programically. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: That master node thing smells like dash/darkcoin, not dashcoin (different coins, long story, dashcoin is a cryptonote, but darkcoin renamed to dash and made it all confusing). You'll want to ask that somewhere dash people congregate, no idea where though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add

```
rpcport=8666
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
```

Working config file example:

```
rpcuser=username
rpcpassword=strong_pass
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
listen=0
daemon=1
server=1
txindex=1
timestampindex=1
rpcthreads=4
rpcport=8666
```

and make sure the port is already open from your internet provider side and your system firewall.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply Adam..I tried the connection after adding 
rpcport=8666
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
in dash.conf file. but its not working. i just pasted the content of the config file below

Comment: rpcuser=username
rpcpassword=password
alertnotify=echo %s | mail -s "DASH Alert" <your@email-address.com>
server=1
daemon=1
addnode=23.23.186.131
listen=1
logtimestamps=1
maxconnections=256
masternode=0
masternodeaddr=127.0.0.1:8666
externalip=127.0.0.1

rpcport=8666
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0

Comment: i also check the connection after changing the ip address to my server's ip address, but its not working. an you pleasde help and suggest a solution..kindly expect your reply..

Comment: Please try to disable master node settings and set the config file as the file I posted. and check if it works. Make sure port open in your firewall and your internet router.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Adam.I just tried  as you said.I changed the confidg file and run the wallet.but i could't connect to the wallet programically..

I check the port number of dashd by using the command sudo netstat -lptu . Then it shows

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 localhost:distinct32        *:*                         LISTEN      5877/dashd

Comment: I also check the port number and application using the command netstat -pnt it shows port number is 9999 under the label foriegn address. i think this is the common port of dash coin. but when i try to connect the plugin with coin using the port number '9999' it shows "Empty reply from server0"...  Ithink the port number which was added in the config file "rpcport=8666" will not affect in the wallet when we trying to start the wallet.

Comment: and i have one more doubt how can i disable the master node? i didnt congire the master node set up section from the below link

Comment: https://planetcrypton.com/install-dash-daemon

Comment: can you please give me a solution..kindly expect your reply..

Comment: Try to install easyBitcoin php

Comment: Thank you Adam.I just change the port number and now its connected...:)

Comment: Don't forget to mark up the answer if that helped.